# Force Firefox & Edge to reload page if URL has a hash value

Tags: javascript, url, firefox, anchor, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to force such browsers as FF and Edge to reload page if URL has a hash value and a user press Enter button in the address bar (like Chrome do)?
Or maybe we could handle some JS events in this case?

P.S. I can't use `load hashchange` events because if the user press Enter button twice - `hashchange` event will not triggers.

P.S.S. Figured out that `popstate` is the event that works well for MS Edge in such situations.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to listen the Keydown event, if click the enter button, using the `window.location.hash` to check whether the url has a hash value, then using the location.reload() method to reload the web page.

code as below:

```
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
        console.log('The hash has changed!')
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == "13") {
            if (window.location.hash) {
                // Fragment exists
                alert("hashed");
                location.reload();
            } else {
                // Fragment doesn't exist
                alert("not exist");
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `keydown` does not work when the user press Enter from the address bar

Comment: @Bohdan Maliar, you could use the window.hashchange event with the window keydown event. The keydown event is used to listen the enter press event.